# How to disable Save button until input field value is validated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have form in the system that has a field that should be validated before user submits the form. The first field on the form is 'Type' input field, and second is 'User ID' input field. Here is working example of my current code:

```js
var data = {
  93169: "John Rives",
  33442: "Mike Cook",
  70354: "Tammy Bull",
  22078: "Nick Adams"
};

$("#user_id").on("keyup", function() {
  var inputFld = $(this),
    msgFld = $(this).closest("div").find(".invalid-feedback");

  if (!inputFld.val().length) {
    inputFld.removeClass("is-invalid").val("");
    msgFld.text("");
    $("#save").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});

$("#user_type").on("change", function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();

  if (inputVal) {
    $("#user_id").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("#user_id").prop("disabled", true);
  }

  // Every time on change reset affiliate field and remove the calss.
  $("#user_id").removeClass("is-invalid").val("");
  $("#user_name").text("N/A");
  $("#save").prop("disabled", false);
});

$("#search_user").on("click", function() {
  var inputFld = $(this).parent().parent().children("input"),
    msgFld = inputFld.closest("div").find(".invalid-feedback"),
    typeID = $("#user_type").val(),
    saveBtn = $("#save"),
    userID = inputFld.val(),
    regex = /^([0-9]{1,5})$/;

  if (userID) {
    if (regex.test(userID) === false) {
      saveBtn.prop("disabled", true);
      inputFld.addClass("is-invalid");
      msgFld.text("User ID has to be numeric 1-5 digits long.");
      $("#user_name").text("N/A");
    } else {
      var userName = data[userID];
      populateUser(userName, inputFld, msgFld, saveBtn);
    }
  } else {
    inputFld.removeClass('is-invalid');
    $('#user_name').text('N/A');
  }
});

function populateUser(userName, inputFld, msgFld, saveBtn) {
  if (!userName) {
    saveBtn.prop('disabled', true);
    inputFld.addClass('is-invalid');
    msgFld.text("User doesn't exist.");
    $("#user_name").text("N/A");
  } else {
    inputFld.removeClass("is-invalid");
    $("#user_name").text(userName);
  }
}
```

```css
#search_user {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a6e6aa2b6e.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form name="my_frm" id="my_frm" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-4">
        <label>User Type:</label>
        <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="user_type" id="user_type" required>
          <option value="">--Select Type--</option>
          <option value="1">Director</option>
          <option value="2">Project Manager</option>
          <option value="3">Assistant Manager</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-4">
        <label class="control-label" for="user_id">User ID:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group addon">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter User ID" disabled>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" name="search_user" id="search_user"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-4">
        <p>User Name:</p>
        <p id="user_name">N/A</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" name="save" id="save">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the example above you will be able to see function with some examples. One thing that I'm concerned about is what if user enters user ID and doesn't click on search button? In that case user is still able to submit the form before user ID is validated. I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent form submission/ disable Save button until User ID has value in the field and that value is not validated. If someone can help me fix that or if you have any suggestions please let me know. I'm also open to hear if you have better ways to achieve this validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a disabled attribute (or class) to your save button, then after the successfull validation, remove it.

In the callback for the button, you will check if the button is disabled or not

```js
$("#save").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    console.log("wait for validation!")
    return;
  }
  //do stuff
});


$("#val").click(function() {
  $("#save").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" type="button" name="save" id="save">Save</button>

<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" name="val" id="val">Validate</button>
```